# Is @EntityGraph applied on the Select or the FROM?

Tags: java, jpa, entitygraph

I am trying to debug a n+1 query issue and I was trying to use EntityGraphs to solve it.

Say I have the following query

```
@Query("select om.organization from OrganizationMember om")
```

And Organization has some extra fields say "attributes"

Would the `EntityGraph` optimization get applied to the select?

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {
  "attributes",
})
@Query("select om.organization from OrganizationMember om")
```

Or should I do it like this?

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {
  "organization.attributes",
})
@Query("select om.organization from OrganizationMember om")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did my experiment, it appears to be on the `from` field.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {
  "organization.attributes",
})
@Query("select om.organization from OrganizationMember om")
```

Doing otherwise would get

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [attributes] on this ManagedType ...